# How to get an A-Frame element via javascript?

Tags: javascript, aframe

I'm new to using A-frame and trying to figure stuff out. Right now i'm diving into the interaction bit. The following javascript I found is from a website i found (can't find the link now) which changes a colour of a box on 'click'. The box appears on a marker (AR) style.

```
// Component to change to a sequential color on click.
AFRAME.registerComponent('cursor-listener', {
    init: function() {
        var lastIndex = -1;
        var COLORS = ['red', 'green', 'blue'];
        this.el.addEventListener('click', function(evt) {
            lastIndex = (lastIndex + 1) % COLORS.length;
            this.setAttribute('material', 'color', COLORS[lastIndex]);
        });
    }
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<a-scene oriscene cursor="rayOrigin: mouse">
    <a-marker preset='custom' type='pattern' url='tiger.patt'>
        <a-box cursor-listener position="0 0 0" color="skyblue"></a-box>
        <a-text id="text-box" value="Clicked!"></a-text>
    </a-marker>
    <!-- add a basic camera  -->
    <!-- So object will land on marker -->
    <a-entity camera></a-entity>
</a-scene>
```

So i'm trying to figure out how to get an element to be used in the script and set its attribute. in my html theres a `<a-text>` which i want to be hidden by default then appear when the box is clicked, since i have the clicking code already. But I'm having trouble hiding it. I tried :

```
var text = document.querySelector('#text-box');
text.setAttribute('visible', false);
```

but it's still visible when I run it on localhost. i did a `console.log(text)` and the console returned a null. So the `a-text` isn't selected?

I thought of setting the element by default as `visible="false"` then change it to true in the click function but also was thinking of how to get the element in the first place?

**EDIT: as requested**

[glitch to try out what im talking about](https://capricious-lip.glitch.me/). I've set it to use the hiro marker.

Sorry for the long post. Thanks in advance!

**EDIT 2: found the solution**

I had to add the primitive attribute to the `<a-text>`. like :

`<a-text id="text-box" value="Clicked!" geometry='primitive: plane'></a-text>` and then of course get it using the `.querySelector`

Comment: Provide a full runnable example. It will be easier to help. [Glitch](https://glitch.com/~aframe) is a good option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<a-text id="text-box" value="Clicked!" visible="false"></a-text>`

Then `document.getElementById('text-box').object3D.visible = true` to show.

Run your code inside a component, not a script tag. You probably had timing issues.

https://aframe.io/docs/0.8.0/introduction/writing-a-component.html

Comment: thanks! but for mobile the text appears without a click after a second. i used your suggestion and works well on laptop browser but for mobile text appears without clicking.

Comment: in regards to the original question, i've marked this as the solution. in regards to the mobile issue, i think i have to ask different question?